# How to access arguments on child resolver from parent call in AWS Appsync

Tags: aws-appsync, resolver

I have two types: Todo and Comment.

```
type Todo {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    description: String
    priority: Int
    status: TodoStatus
    comments: [Comment]
}
```

```
type Comment {
    todoid: ID!
    commentid: String!
    content: String
}
```

Then I have a Query getTodo but the thing is I want to include a content arg that filters the comment (child) if the string passed is in the content of Comment.

```
getTodo(id: ID!, content: String!): Todo
```

I have tried attaching a resolver to comments (under Todo). If I add a filter here, how will I be able to get the ctx.args.content which was passed in getTodo(id: ID!, content: String!).

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        ## Provide a query expression. **
        "expression": "todoid = :id",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":id" : {
                "S" : "${ctx.args.id}"
            }
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "expression": "contains(content, :content)",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":content": {
                "S": "${ctx.args.content}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if I remove this filter and leave it like this:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        ## Provide a query expression. **
        "expression": "todoid = :id",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":id" : {
                "S" : "${ctx.args.id}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How will I modify getTodo Resolver to fetch comments (with content that contains the string passed)?
Can I do it like this (accessing if comments.content contains the content string args passed):

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        ## Provide a query expression. **
        "expression": "id = :id",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":id" : {
                "S" : "${ctx.args.id}"
            }
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "expression": "contains(comments.content, :content)",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":content": {
                "S": "${ctx.args.content}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `${context.source.content}`? That should give you access to the parent args from with in a nested resolver.

Answer (score 1):

The GraphQL arguments you are accessing via `$ctx.args` are available at the **field** level. So when you access them when resolving the `Post.comments` field, you get back all the arguments on that field and that field only.

So to get the content string argument you could update your `Todo` type to:

```
type Todo {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    description: String
    priority: Int
    status: TodoStatus
    comments(content: String): [Comment]
}
```

Another way, if you don't want to expose the content argument on the `Post.comments` field and keep the argument on the `Query.getTodo` field, you could pass the arguments via the source. In your `Query.getTodo` resolver you could return the `content` field as part of the todo result. You would then be able to access it inside the `Todo.comments` resolver via `$ctx.source.content`.

Comment: Hi, how can I access the content args that is passed in comments in the comments resolver?

Comment: Will I be able to access content in Todo.contents resolver if I pass it in the result of getTodo resolver using this:
`#set($result = $ctx.result)`
`#set($result.content = $util.parseJson($ctx.args.content))`
`$util.toJson($result)`

Comment: Which solution are you going for? If you are ok with changing your schema by adding the content argument on Todo.comments field, then you can just access the arguments via $ctx.args.content in the Todo.comments resolver.